# Displaying html page containing d3.js using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

As far as I have understood correctly, it is possible to display an html file in another html's div using the following code:

**index.hml**

```
<script> 
  $(function() {
    $("#includedChart1").load("chart1.html"); 
  }); 
</script> 

<body>
  <div id="includedChart1"></div>
</body>
```

However, the **chart1.html** that I am trying to load contains the following d3.js related code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 30px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg2 = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 20,
    diameter = +svg2.attr("width"),
    g = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);

d3.json("data.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg2
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});




</script>
```

While the index.html displays other html files, when I load the above code, it just displays blank page and nothing else.

What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: The way it is written, the possible reason could be that d3.js has not loaded at the moment when the following script begins to work with the d3 variable. Have you checked the browser console for the «d3 is undefined» error?

Comment: I just can't believe I spent half of the day to understand that! So, adding the line <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> in my index.html should solve the problem?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem. If I create multiple divs, the graphs seems to get merged. Say, chart1.html and chart2.html has same code but loads different data, then I cannot display them in multiple divs?

Comment: Yes, if you include d3 from the index.html, and execulte .load() from jQuery(document).ready() it will solve part of the problem.

Comment: Concerning multiple divs. You have to code some logic to show the result in different elements. Check with the [d3.select() documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#select) — it selects the first element matching the selector. So, «same code» will use the first SVG element on the page. While coding some logic, you'll eventually get rid of load()-ing full HTML files, and start loading only data to be processed with a single script in index.html :)